# Scraping AJAX generated table to download PDFs in bulk

Tags: json, ajax, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to download (or alternatively open and save) approximately 30,000 PDF documents. The documents that are only accessible through a 3rd party service provider's website/platform (there are no ethical dilemmas here).

The website is secure and needs to be logged into (I have access) and the table is generated via AJAX. The report I intend on reading from has a URL of the form https://sub.website.com/au/report/index?id=1001# that doesn't change when dates or other filters change. In total there are 180,000+ table entries, not all have an associated invoice and not all invoices are required.

[image: Maintenance Activity report screenshot]

Using Chrome DevTools I can see the elements; table name is #reportResults, invoice details are in a html  element.

[image: Table element with Chrome DevTools]

There also looks to be an API but I don't know where to start here either.

[image]

How do I scrape data from this using VBA? I have downloaded the JSON.bas module recommended in other solutions for scraping JSON and AJAX. But for this situation I don't know how to use it and where to go from here.

I'm handy with VBA but have no experience with any other languages.

Comment: The URL may not change but is there any XHR activity you can capture using dev tools?

Comment: More digging and I found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008526/vba-html-scraping-problems) which stepped me through what I needed to do. Now I'm just trying to get the authentication working and there seem to be PLENTY of posts on that.